# How can I fix Chrome infinite redirect?

Tags: google-chrome

I am running Chrome 74 on Mac OS X 10.13.3.

I am doing some development locally, and a server misconfiguration caused a redirect on localhost:4503/content-path.html. I fixed the issue with my server and I am not seeing the infinite redirect issue in Incognito mode or in Firefox.

I cleared all the site data associated with localhost (cookies, cache, etc).

I also tried to clear the DNS cache at chrome://net-internals/#dns.

No luck.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an Chrome add on that was using redirects improperly. I disabled it and Voila! It works.

(Was a little confusing because the redirects in my server occurred at the same time that the add on started acting strangely).

Comment: Can you share the name of the addon for others who find this question?  Thanks!

Comment: It is an add on that was only internally available at the company I work for. Not externally available.